# Оптимальное решение для создания пула потоков с динамически изменяемым размером

Tags: java

Стоит задача опроса оборудования в несколько потоков, их количество задается в БД.

На данный момент в вечном цикле каждый раз создаю новый пул потоков размера, указанного в БД. Есть ли более оптимальное решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете один `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
int minThreadCount = 1;
int maxThreadCount = 5;
ThreadPoolExecutor executors = 
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                     minThreadCount, 
                     maxThreadCount, 
                     10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
                     new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
```

И в процессе работы, динамически, изменяете у него количество потоков, следующим образом:

```
executors.setCorePoolSize(10);
executors.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
```